# The command "pipenv run" worked fine yesterday. Why I get an AttributeError today?

Tags: python, date, time, raspbian, pipenv

I have a python script which I called via

```
pipenv run python3 script.py
```

Yesterday it worked fine, but today I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 7, in <module>
from pipenv import cli
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/__init__.py", line 17,in <module>
from .cli import cli
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 89, in <module>
if ((now.tm_mon == 10) and (now.tm_day == 30)) or ((now.tm_mon == 10) and (now.tm_day == 31)):
AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'tm_day'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 7, in <module>
from pipenv import cli
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
```

I assume that it may have something to do with the new month starting, but I can't find a way to fix this (strange) problem.

Some further information:

The script runs on a raspberry pi. It uses the requests and the Adafruit_DHT library. I don't do any time-regarding operations in the python script by myself.

Could I kindly ask you to help me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bug, change the date or update to the latest version from github.

Comment: See https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/commit/033b969d094ba2d80f8ae217c8c604bc40160b03

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just installed pipenv 2 days ago so I hadn't thought this would be a problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be. You just happen to have hit a really, really dumb bug - pipenv breaks because a cute halloween easter egg was implemented poorly/not tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make on reinstall, direct repository latest version!

`pip install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv.git`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is a bug in pipenv. I've submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/issues/786)

Comment: There's a fix for it already at https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/commit/033b969d094ba2d80f8ae217c8c604bc40160b03